# Getting my server's requesting IP address from an outgoing cURL request?

Tags: http, curl, request

I'm making a request to an external API that accepts my request and returns information. I want to know what my server's host address is based on what the external API sees. Is there a way to get this information from a Command Line cURL request (or other method)?

My server is behind a bunch of firewalls in a VPC on Amazon AWS, so I'm not sure what my request looks like and where it's coming from.

Currently I'm making this request and don't see the info I need:

```bash
curl -v 'http://www.apihost.com/request/url'
```

Answer (score 8):

I was inspired by @Atsby's answer and found this article:
http://tecadmin.net/5-commands-to-get-public-ip-using-linux-terminal/

Here are it's suggestions:

```
curl ipecho.net/plain; echo

curl icanhazip.com

curl ifconfig.me

wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo

wget http://observebox.com/ip -O - -q ; echo
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what my server's host address is [...]

The simplest way is to fetch a page that echoes back your IP address, like http://www.whatismyip.com/

Note that this isn't the most *reliable* way, as it depends on such services to be available. There are AWS APIs you can use to determine the public-facing IP of an AWS box.